# Codeigniter Three Table Join, displaying image problem

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, frameworks

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework and MySQL for database. I want to display the specific floorplan(img) of the room also display building without rooms.

I have 3 tables:

**tblbldg - Building**

- id (pk)
- name

**tblroom - Room**

- id
- name
- floor
- building_id (fk)

**tblfloorplan - Floorplan**

- id
- floor
- building_id (fk)
- img

I tried this code but it end up mixing img, like building1 floor1 displays the same floorplan with building 2 floor1:

> ```
> public function get_rooms(){
>     $this->db->select('tblroom.id,
>         tblroom.name,
>         tblroom.floor,
>         tblbldg.name as building_name,
>         tblfloorplan.img');
>     $this->db->from('tblroom');
>     $this->db->join('tblbldg',"tblbldg.id = tblroom.building_id");
>     $this->db->join('tblfloorplan',"tblfloorplan.floor = tblroom.floor");
>     return $this->db->get();
> }
> ```

Comment: can you show us your DB output expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This,**

```
public function get_rooms(){
       $this->db->select('tblroom.id,
            tblroom.name,
            tblroom.floor,
            tblbldg.name as building_name,
            tblfloorplan.img');
        $this->db->from('tblroom');
        $this->db->join('tblbldg',"tblbldg.id = tblroom.building_id");
        $this->db->join('tblfloorplan',"tblbldg.id = tblfloorplan.building_id and tblfloorplan.floor = tblroom.floor");
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir it works! .. can you also help me, i want to display buildings without room and floorplan, cause the query only display room with room and floorplan..

Comment: ya sure, do you have that query now?

Comment: yes sir, it works perfectly, my problem regarding floorplan img mixing solved.